# quickly Remove row from datatable which not find in another datatable

Tags: c#

here i have two datatable dtPartMaster([Part Number Exported]) and dtPartBackUp([Part Number Backup],[weight]) 
now i want to remove the rows in dtPartBackUp which [part Number Backup] not exists in dtPartMaster([Part Number Exported])
my logic is this but it take long time to process billon record

```
 button1_click()
    {  int count = 0;
//line remove for clearity

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtPartBackUp.Rows)
    {
      if (!CheckPartNumber(dr["Part Number Backup"].ToString(), dtPartMaster))
       {
           dtPartBackUp.Rows[count].Delete();
       }

    count++;
    }

    dtPartBackUp.AcceptChanges();// to accept changes

    }

 private bool CheckPartNumber(string PartNumber, DataTable dt)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            DataRow dr = dt.Select("[Part Number Exported] Like '" + PartNumber + "'").FirstOrDefault();
            if (dr != null)
                flag = true;

            dr = null;
            return flag;

        }
```

thanks in advance
Amrit

Comment: `return 0 row`, which method returns 0 rows?

Comment: CompareTwoDataTable() return datatable that have 0 row

Comment: and first method 'Check()' work properly but take too long time

Comment: Why do you use 'Like' in Check method? Why not simply '='?

Comment: The only way to achieve high perfromance in any database is to use proper SQL statements. In your case you are trying to use what is essentially a client-side cursor to handle a billion records => Extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested),

This should return you the list of rows those are both in dt1 and dt2 on the basis of id column (I am considering your id and id2 column is of type string)

```
var rows = (from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            join  r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on r1.Field<string>("id") equals r2.Field<string>("id2")
            select r1).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Pawan , you code work but not correct.return only few rows

Comment: Hello Pawan,Please check my code again i posted it as clear for you to understand what i want to say thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0;i< dtPartBackUp.Rows.count;i++)
    {
      if (!CheckPartNumber(dr["Part Number Backup"].ToString(), dtPartMaster))
       {
           dtPartBackUp.Rows.removeat(i);
i--;
       }


    }

    dtPartBackUp.AcceptChanges();// to accept changes

    }

 private bool CheckPartNumber(string PartNumber, DataTable dt)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            DataRow dr = dt.Select("[Part Number Exported] Like '" + PartNumber + "'").FirstOrDefault();
            if (dr != null)
                flag = true;

            dr = null;
            return flag;

        }
```